# R - apply data.file function on each file in a folder and export them

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I'm looking for some help with the following.
I have many files in a folder, each of them is a txt file containing 16 columns like this:

```
head(a1)
```

| v1 | v2 | ... | v16 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.0742 | 1.1520 | ... | 5.6852 |
| -1.4071 | 1.1848 | ... | 2.7629 |

which I want to transform into a single long column, using the library data.table :

```
library(data.table)    
setDT(a1)
a1<-melt(a1)[, .(value)]
```

| v1 |
| --- |
| 2.0742 |
| -1.4071 |
| ... |
| 2.7629 |

What I want to do is automate with a for loop reading each file in the folder, applying the function melt and exporting into another folder the transformed files.
Any idea from  where to start?

Comment: What is about to keep *all* data in *one* large data.table (with an additional column indicating the source file of each row) instead of saving single files to disk? How many rows has each file on average?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to first load all data then transform and export. Each file has about 7000 rows

Comment: How many files do you have?

Comment: I have 100 files divided in two folders approximately 50/50

Answer (score 1):

According to [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72337510/r-apply-data-file-function-on-each-file-in-a-folder-and-export-them#comment127793885_72337510), there are 2 directories with 50 files with 7000 rows and 16 columns each. Assuming all columns are of type double which require 8 Bytes each, the total data volume is somewhat around 100 MBytes which can be stored and processed *in memory*.

So, my suggestion is to read all data *in one go* and combine and process it in one large data.table *in memory*.

Here is what I would do using my preferred tools:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
file_names <- list.files(test_dir, full.names = TRUE)
all_wide <- lapply(file_names, fread) %>% 
  set_names(basename(file_names)) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "file_name")
all_long <- melt(all_wide, id.vars = "file_name")
all_long
```

> ```
>            file_name variable     value
>               <char>   <fctr>     <num>
>       1: File001.txt       V1  101.0000
>       2: File001.txt       V1  101.0000
>       3: File001.txt       V1  101.0000
>       4: File001.txt       V1  101.0000
>       5: File001.txt       V1  101.0001
>      ---                               
> 5599996: File050.txt      V16 5016.0700
> 5599997: File050.txt      V16 5016.0700
> 5599998: File050.txt      V16 5016.0700
> 5599999: File050.txt      V16 5016.0700
> 5600000: File050.txt      V16 5016.0700
> ```

This processes all files in directory `test_dir`.

Memory consumption can be displayed by

```
tables()
```

> ```
>        NAME      NROW NCOL  MB                         COLS KEY
> 1: all_long 5,600,000    3 107     file_name,variable,value    
> 2: all_wide   350,000   17  45 file_name,V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,...    
> 3:        d     7,000   16   1        V1,V2,V3,V4,V5,V6,...    
> Total: 153MB
> ```

The source of each row can be identified by `file_name`.

#### Data for testing

**Warning:** The code below will create a subdirectory and `nfil` files in the `TMPDIR` directory.

```
library(data.table)
nfil <- 50 # number of files
nrow <- 7000 # number of rows per file
ncol <- 16 # number of columns
test_dir <- file.path(tempdir(), paste0("files_in_", as.integer(Sys.time())))
print(test_dir)
dir.create(test_dir)
for (ifil in seq(nfil)) {
  d <- data.table()
  for (icol in seq(ncol)) set(d, , paste0("V", icol), ifil * 100 + icol + seq(nrow)/10^(ceiling(log10(nrow))+1))
  fwrite(d, file.path(test_dir, sprintf("File%03i.txt", ifil)))
  print(d)
}
dir(test_dir)
```